# Legend desepear when i use "scale_fill_gradientn" in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, heatmap

I have a problem in my code somewhere but i can't figure out where it is.
I try to make a heatmap using p-adj values that i got from an ANOVA + Tukey test.
The thing is that the p-adj values range from 1 to 1e-9, so i was thinking about using a log scale for the continuous gradient.

I've tried the code below, but it seems that `scale_fill_gradientn` make my legend disappear for a reason that I don't understand. Also, my "theme" code lines don't work either.

Here is the code I'm using:

```r
var1<-c("BB", "BB", "BB", "H", "H", "H", "ML", "ML", "ML")
var2<-c("Fraction 5", "Fraction 6", "Fraction 7", "Fraction 5", "Fraction 6", "Fraction 7", "Fraction 5", "Fraction 6", "Fraction 7")
value <- c(2.172310e-01, 4.002828e-04, 1.336477e-03, 5.120373e-06, 9.429461e-07, 6.303150e-08, 1.000000e+00, 2.066473e-01, 5.715313e-01)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, value)

ggplot(data = df, aes(var1, var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("lightcoral", "white", "royalblue"), 
                       guide="colorbar",
                       values = rescale(c(0.00005, 0.0005, 0.005, 0.05, 0.5, 1)),
                       breaks=c(0.00005, 0.0005, 0.005, 0.05, 0.5, 1) %>% log,
                       label = c("0.00005", "0.0005", "0.005", "0.05", "0.5", "1"))+
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(title = element_text("p adj"))) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text("Fractions")) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text("Total")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("H", "ML", "BB")) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, size = 10, 
                                   hjust = 1)) + coord_fixed()
```

Is there a way I can make a log scale using this function, or another for a heatmap ? And posssibly adjust the breaks and labels of my legend so that the "0.05" value on the scale is at the "white" color, at the interface between the colors "lightcoral" and "royalblue" ?

EDIT: I changed the code to add a dataframe you can plot with the ggplot code. I've allready tried the following to use "trans=log10" and the legend appears:

```r
ggplot(data = df, aes(var1, var2, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradientn(trans="log10", colours = c("lightcoral", "white", "royalblue"))+
  guides(fill = guide_colourbar(title = element_text("p adj"))) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text("Fractions")) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text("Total")) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("H", "ML", "BB")) +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, size = 10, 
                                   hjust = 1)) + coord_fixed()
```

But i can't set the breaks of my legend manually and set the "white" color (interface between "lightcoral" and "royalblue") to a certain value (0.05 per example) using "breaks", "labels" and "midpoint".
I want to set manually the legend because i want to plot multiple graphs with one legend, and that using just "trans="log10"", sets the gradient depending on the data plotted, so the legend will be correct only for one of my graphs and not all of them.

Comment: Yes, you can pass `trans = "log"` to `scale_fill_gradientn`. If you need more help, please post a small reproducible example.

Comment: It does seem strange that you set `aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")`, when you don't map a `colour` aesthetic. I'd delete that argument.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments, I deleted "aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")", but it changes nothing to the graph (maybe because I didn't map "colour" aesthetic). I've edited what i posted to help you understand what i'm trying to do, I hope it helps